# Django is not updating my database after submitting my form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-database

I have created a model and a form, both are working correctly, and I have added data to the database using the admin module

**models.py**

```
class Client(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)
    lastname = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=15)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="company")
    position = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=15)
    country = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)')
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, max_length=100, default="this_is@n_example.com")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    phone = PhoneField(default="(XX)-XXX-XXX")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.firstname}'
```

**forms.py**

```
class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('firstname', 'lastname',"position",'country','email','phone')
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def add_client(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        client_form = ClientForm(instance=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if client_form.is_valid():
            client_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'You have successfully added a client')
        else:
            messages.success(request, "Error Updating your form")
    else:
        client_form = ClientForm(instance=request.user)

    return render(request,
                  "account/add_client.html",
                  {'client_form':client_form})
```

add_client.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Client Information {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h1> Client Form</h1>
  <p>Please use the form below to add a new client to the database:</p>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ client_form.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Save changes"></p>
    </form>


{% endblock %}
```

Everything seems to be working fine, I can submit data in the website and I get a message stating that the the submission when fine, however, when I check the admin website and inspect the database, I can't see the new data added, essentially the form is not submitting data and I don't get an error

[10/Jul/2021 18:36:24] "GET /account/add_client/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12385
[10/Jul/2021 18:36:36] "POST /account/add_client/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12616

Does anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: try deleting this line in your view: {else: messages.success(request, "Error Updating your form")} so you can see form's error messages.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, I did it and there is no error:

Comment: ```@login_required
def add_client(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        client_form = ClientForm(instance=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if client_form.is_valid():
            client_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'You have successfully added a client')
        #else:
            #messages.success(request, "Error Updating your form")
    else:
        client_form = ClientForm(instance=request.user)

    return render(request,
                  "account/add_client.html",
                  {'client_form':client_form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice my mistake is in the form, I should have not use the request.user in the instance, the @login_required is enough informtion.

Please see amended code:

```
@login_required
def add_client(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        client_form = ClientForm(request.POST)
        if client_form.is_valid():
            client_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'You have successfully added a client')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('add_client'))
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Error Updating your form")
    else:
        client_form = ClientForm()

    return render(request,
                  "account/add_client.html",
                  {'client_form':client_form})
```